# FQL query to fetch only those records which have a birthday.

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to fetch only those records from fb which have a birthday specified, I dont want null records. I have the following query:

```
String fqlQuery = "{" +
                        "'friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()'," +
                        "'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name, pic_square, birthday FROM user WHERE uid IN" +
                        "(SELECT uid2 FROM #friends)'," + 
                        "}";
```

it fetches everything, I tried the following:

```
String fqlQuery = "{" +
                        "'friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()'," +
                        "'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name, pic_square, birthday FROM user WHERE uid IN" +
                        "(SELECT uid2 FROM #friends)'," + "AND birthday != null"+
                        "}";
```

It does not give me any result, what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FQL, just use `AND something` to check if `something` is not null.

Here is your FQL query corrected:

```
{
'friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()',
'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name, pic_square, birthday FROM user 
               WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM #friends) 
                 AND birthday'
}
```

Java code:

```
String fqlQuery = "{" +
                        "'friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()'," +
                        "'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name, pic_square, birthday FROM user WHERE uid IN" +
                        "(SELECT uid2 FROM #friends) AND birthday'"+
                  "}";
```

Comment: Also one last query, can I fetch the private information like phone number and email?

Comment: You can't get phone numbers, though the email can be retrieved through the `email` field.